# How can I create WebP MBTiles?

Tags: raster, mbtiles, tools, format

Using the "Generate XYZ Tiles" command from "Raster tools" it is possible to create a MBTiles format file containing either PNG or JPG images. I would like to create an MBTiles file containing WebP formatted images. The WebP raster driver is already installed, so is this not possible, a missing UI option, or is there something else I need to do to make this possible?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Generate XYZ Tiles (MBTiles) tool uses GDAL to [generate the output](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/TilesXYZ.py#L359).

The GDAL MBTiles driver documentation states it only supports [PNG and JPG output](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html#tile-formats), so may only support <= [version 1.2 of the MBTiles spec](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.2/spec.md#content). WebP support was added to the MBTiles spec at [v. 1.3](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.3/spec.md#content).

There is an open GDAL enhancement ticket ([#3437](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3437)) requesting WebP support be added.

So in short, doesn't look like you can enable WebP output with the QGIS Generate XYZ Tiles (MBTiles) tool.

However, [maptiler engine](https://www.maptiler.com/engine/) supports MBTiles and WebP output and has a free desktop version. I haven't used it so can't comment on it other than that.

Comment: Thanks for all the docs links

Comment: @MatthewHerbst try https://www.maptiler.com/engine/

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood MBTiles is SQLite so you can use SQLite and PIL to convert the images to webp. here is a sketch of how i have done it for tiles that start as png8. I am new to SQLite so feel free to tell me how to tighten it up.

```
import sqlite3 
import io
from PIL import Image

conn = sqlite3.connect(FullPathToFile)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT rowid,* FROM tiles')
data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    tile_data = row[tData] 
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(tile_data)) #https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#reading-from-binary-data
    im.save(stream, format="WebP", lossless=True, quality=100, method=5) #https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp
    imagebytes = stream.getvalue()
    try:
        sql_update_query = "UPDATE tiles SET tile_data=? WHERE rowid=?"
        cursor.execute(sql_update_query, (imagebytes,rID))
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to update sqlite table", error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create tms tiles with gdal

```
gdal2tiles.py --zoom=18 --tiledriver=WEBP --webp-quality=50 inputFiles.vrt tiles
```

then use https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil and run

```
mb-util --image_format=webp --scheme=tms tiles yourOutputfile.mbtiles
```

Btw: if you want to work with multiple input files, start with the following command to build a virtual mosaic:
`gdalbuildvrt inputFiles.vrt input/*.jpg`